# Expand dictionary to JSON fields

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

We have DTO class like this:

```cs
public class DTO
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, string> CustomFields { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to serialize/deserialize DTO by ServiceStack to JSON where CustomFields is expanded as DTO fields. For example

```cs
new DTO 
{
    Number = 42
    Title = "SuperPuper"
    CustomFields = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Description", "HelloWorld"}, {"Color", "Red"}}
}
```

serialize to

```js
{
    "Number":42,
    "Title":"SuperPuper",
    "Description":"HelloWorld",
    "Color":"Red"
}
```

How can I achieve this?

- All dictionary fields must be represented as JSON object fields during serialization.
- All fields of incoming JSON object that are not fields of DTO must be put to Dictionary during deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Newtonsoft library you can do this:

```
   DTO Test = new DTO
   {
       Number = 42,
       Title = "SuperPuper",
       CustomFields = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Description", "HelloWorld" }, { "Color", "Red" } }
   };

    String Json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Test);

    Json = Json.Replace("\"CustomFields\":{", "");
    Json = Json.Replace("}}", "}");
```

The resulting json string looks like this:

```
{"Number":42,"Title":"SuperPuper","Description":"HelloWorld","Color":"Red"}
```

[Edit]

I'm not going to do ALL your work...this should get you started:

```
// to reconstruct the object
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject MyObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json) as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject;

// Create a new object here.

foreach( var Token in MyObject)
{         
    // sample  
    if (Token.Key == "Number")
    {
        // populate the fields of the new object with Token.Value
    }      
}
```